# Using jQuery .Live to persist .Net UpdatePanel partial Postback Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am new to jQuery.  I am trying to convert this jQuery code so that it persists after I call a .Net Ajax partial postback in my page. The code below runs when the page initially loads, but not after I do a postback in the updatePanel.

Do I need to use the .live function somewhere else in my code to get this to work?

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {


    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event

    $("ul.tabs li").live('click', (function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    }));

});


</script>
```

Comment: Kind of confused how you're calling `noConflict` and then using `$` right after that and you say it works at all...

Comment: oh sorry - forgot to tell you that I had another jQuery app in the page and had to use the noConflict to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better bet might be to hook the add_pageLoaded event of the PageRequestManager. This is [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx) that describes how to do it. Then put the jQuery stuff in a method and call it in the event.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Your link led me to a few more searches on the topic, and I found a GREAT tutorial.  It really helped me learn the differences in postbacks.
Link Here:
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/jQuery-and-Asynchronous-Postback-with-UpdatePanel-Issue-635.php

I hope this helps out someone else in the future.

Regards,
Edward